# How to hide "project name" in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing web application but when launched my application after deploying it on *IIS*; it shows the complete path of *aspx* file as mentioned below.

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/Viewer.aspx?cid=1394794287&sid=12884&uType=InternalUser
```

I want to encrypt only the following part of *url*

```
http://localhost/PROJECT_NAME/Viewer.aspx
```

So that it shows in browsers like

```
http://localhost/SOME_OTHERNAME/Viewer.aspx
```

Comment: Define "encrypt". How do you want it to look? And why do you use a totally outdated web technology for a new project?

Comment: why? what's the use? If you encrypt, it wont hit where it should.

Comment: I mean i don't want to show this path rather some different path is shown in browser like http://SOME_OTHERNAME/Viewer.aspx

Comment: @CoderMan That is not encryption, and encryption is not needed here. Instead, [Create a new Virtual Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) - then the server can then be configured to map SOME_OTHERNAME to PROJECT_NAME (so the user never sees PROJECT_NAME). Or you could possibly just update the current Virtual Directory mappings, but start looking there ..

Comment: @Amit: Can you please introduce me with latest technology for my application?

Comment: You can't mate, unless you use Virtual directory

Comment: @TomTom This is Asp.Net it's not outdated, doesn't matter if its web forms of mvc.

Comment: @CoderMan I've updated your question (based on your commend), adding in the example mapping and removing some of the incorrect uses of "encrypt". Getting the terminology right, and providing an example in the question body itself, plays a huge role in directing [initial] responses.

Comment: I have to create virtual directoty in my application and place my pages in that directory?

Comment: @CoderMan the term you're looking for is URL Rewrite, you can do this in IIS or the web.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you have to use concept of dynamic URL rewriting in ASP.Net.

You can dynamically "re-write" URLs and/or have the ability to publish cleaner URL end-points within their ASP.NET web applications.  This blog post summarizes a few approaches you can take to cleanly map or rewrite URLs with ASP.NET, and have the option to structure the URLs of your application however you want.

Why does URL mapping and rewriting matter?
The most common scenarios where developers want greater flexibility with URLs are:

1) Handling cases where you want to restructure the pages within your web application, and you want to ensure that people who have bookmarked old URLs don't break when you move pages around.  Url-rewriting enables you to transparently forward requests to the new page location without breaking browsers.

2) Improving the search relevancy of pages on your site with search engines like Google, Yahoo and Live.  Specifically, URL Rewriting can often make it easier to embed common keywords into the URLs of the pages on your sites, which can often increase the chance of someone clicking your link.  Moving from using querystring arguments to instead use fully qualified URL's can also in some cases increase your priority in search engine results.  Using techniques that force referring links to use the same case and URL entrypoint can also avoid diluting your pagerank across multiple URLs, and increase your search results.

In a world where search engines increasingly drive traffic to sites, extracting any little improvement in your page ranking can yield very good ROI to your business.  Increasingly this is driving developers to use URL-Rewriting and other SEO (search engine optimization) techniques to optimize sites (note that SEO is a fast moving space, and the recommendations for increasing your search relevancy evolve monthly).  For a list of some good search engine optimization suggestions,

There are three approaches to implement such scenarios -
1) Use Request.PathInfo Parameters Instead of QueryStrings 
2) Using an HttpModule to Perform URL Rewriting
3) Using an HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7
4) ISAPIRewrite to enable Extension-less URL Rewriting for IIS5 and IIS6

So, please look upon these scenarios. Choose the best for your application requirement.